# Electrical Engineering Top User Swag!

Tags: discussion

**We want to congratulate and thank everyone that helped this site and community grow healthily into what they are today!** Yes, yes, you graduated a long time ago, but you recently got an update design and we also have some brand new site swag to give out to you all!

If you can find your name among the top 72 users in the first two pages [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all), we have a surprise for you! We want to send you a token of our appreciation for being among the most prolific users in this community! As such, we're sending you a little box, inside which you'll find:

[image: A T-SHIRT!]

**T-SHIRTS!!!!!!!**

[image: STICKERS!]

**STICKERS!!!!!!!**

I'll be reaching out to you later today with a link to a form: be sure to fill out the form as soon as you're able to do so! You'll have two weeks to do it, after which I'll close the form and take care of sending all of the swag your way! It should take from 6 to 8 weeks for the package to be delivered to you!

If you're not on the list, don't worry too much about it — we've got some extra swag stored we can send to you for events and such!

**Thanks to all of you for making this site great!**

Comment: Can we retroactively do this for 2015 please? ;)

Comment: @PlasmaHH I'm sorry I'm not familiar with this community, but why 2015, and what particular date (doing this requires an exact date)? We considered also pulling the top 72 from when the site originally graduated in 2011(?) but it would just pull a bunch of users who don't really visit the site anymore along with the normal crowd.

Comment: @mostly because according to http://stackexchange.com/leagues/58/year/electronics/2015-01-01 I would be under the first 72 ;) on a more serious note, the page you linked to is purely total rep, isn't it? It's probably hard to find good criteria, but in that list there might be people that didn't actively do a lot in the last year or so, but I guess "rep earned by questions posted within the last X years" is a hard thing to figure out

Comment: Can the box also contain hugs and cuddles?

Comment: @Asmyldof: only for the very very very needy.

Comment: Argh! I'm #89 :)

Comment: I never even got my m&tv swag...

Comment: Also white tees? Those ain't gonna last :/

Comment: Woop, #33 :) Me like free stuff.

Comment: Yay, swag! No election required this time! ;)

Comment: @Passerby You're supposed to put them in a frame, on the wall above the fireplace. Not wear them, of course.

Comment: @dim Tell that to my Jelly THANKS shirt!

Comment: Wow, I'm in the top 50 :-) Lucky me :-) And I haven't been on this site for that long it seems. Thanks for the shirts, great initiative.

Comment: Awesome :-) Glad I'm still #10.

Comment: yay I qualify too! great :)

Comment: Good reason to come back after my summer break :-)

Comment: I'm sure @Olin can't be bothered with such mundane things. If not can I have his as well ? [[ YES- just kidding of course]].

Comment: Argh! I'm, only #81! Sigh! ***(...goes grabbing a beer...)*** :-D

Comment: Oh :( missed out. Could the stickers get sent to the next 10

Comment: Mmmh. Wait a minute! Top ***72*** users?!? I think I found a bug in SE network system! That can't be right. THE right answer is *top **42** users*! (..still drinking beer..)

Comment: Cool.  Could you label the cathode and anode please, so then I can just look at my shirt if I forget which is which again?

Comment: ^ this. And also please add Ohm's law, I always need to think a split second when I need to calculate something.

Comment: Dang it, I missed the email and just now saw this.  Sigh...

Comment: SWAG sometimes means "Scientific Wild Assed Guess" yet in Silicon Valley, California in the 80's during monthly Project Status meetings, it meant "Super Wild Assed Guess" for any measurable parameter, understood by all.

Comment: Status update @animuson?

Comment: @Passerby Seconded. No sign of anything my way yet either.

Comment: @Passerby The final vector files for the designs haven't been sent to the warehouse yet for production. The design team has been a bit backlogged with other projects recently. I've been bugging them hoping that they'll do these three pending ones though.

Comment: Oh I was afraid it was perhaps a regional thing. It's winter anyway, too cold for a T-shirt right now ;o)

Comment: I got my stuff a few days ago.  It looks nice, thanks.  However, I'm curious.  I thought you guys were in New York City.  I noticed the package was shipped from Woburn MA, and it was from "Stack Exchange", not some T-shirt printing company.  Where are you guys really located?

Comment: @Olin The provider we use is in MA, but still ships out using our company name.

Comment: @animuson love it, sticker officially stuck on my laptop cover! thanks super fun

Comment: @LorenzoDonati surely for our site it should be the to 64 or 128 users...

Answer (score 5):

Any chance of being able to order a sticker?

Comment: Or a Tee for that matter (to Europe)

Comment: You might as well call congress and ask if they will sell you one of those medals.

Comment: I bought a cool gold-looking medal from a guy in Norway one time!

Comment: @MarkHarrison Cool! I guess it was one of those "*Norbert* prize" medals ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Got my swag!  Nice stuff! Thanks

Comment: Got mine on Saturday too.  Looks nice.

Comment: I'm in Germany and my stuff arrived today.

Comment: Got the tee in Italy too! We should post happy pictures of proud tee wearers

Comment: Got mine last friday and wore it all weekend and now it stinks. How rude of it. Where are people putting their stickers? Is it a car windshield thing or should it proudly go on a window or door so that no foul passover fate will befall us?

Comment: I put one on my laptop. My laptop is kinda full of stickers tho, so I figured it would be nice to add one.

Answer (score 2):

My parcel arrived yesterday as well. Looking forward to the confused looks ("What's *that* logo from?")

Answer (score -5):

[image]

Shine a different light on the subject?

We should start a caption contest.

"(can) We communicate"

or "I think the emitter is missing the point...."

Comment: I don't see what you're saying - is your bandgap above 1.8 eV?